# Write trickleUp and trickleDown routines for make_heap

Tags: c++

I have a `Nx` by `Ny` vector of objects `A`.

- `A` has members `a` and `b`.
- If member `b` meets a certain criteria, it is added to a vector of pointers `heapItem`.
- I then want to use the function `std::make_heap` to create a minimum heap.

Then, in my code, I want to change the value of `A[i][j].b` present in the heap and want the heap to reflect these changes.

For this, I would need to write a `filterUp` and `filterDown` routine. My problem is that I do not know the location of the `A[i][j].b` in the heap. Is there any way I can find out or another way to write the `trickleUp` & `trickleDown` routines? I don't want to constantly call the `make_heap` function for it might be costly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

struct A
{
  A(){}

  A(int av, int bv):a(av),b(bv){}

  int a, b;
};

struct MinHeap
{
    bool operator()(const A* lhs, const A* rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->b > rhs->b;
    }
};

int main()
{
  int Nx=4;
  int Ny=3;
  int cnt=0;
  std::vector<A*> heapItem;

  A gridPt[Nx][Ny];  
  for(int i=0; i<Nx; ++i)  // initialize grid of A objects
  {
    for(int j=0; j<Ny; ++j)
    {
      gridPt[i][j].a=i*(-j)+2*j+i+j;
      gridPt[i][j].b=i+j*(-2)+4;

      if(gridPt[i][j].b>0)  // add selected A objects to heap
      { 
          heapItem.push_back(&gridPt[i][j]);
          cnt++;
      }
    }
  }

    std::make_heap(heapItem.begin(), heapItem.end(), MinHeap());  //make heap

    gridPt[1][2].b=3; //this object is in heap. need to call a filterUp or filterDown routine to retain min heap structure

    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; count<heapItem.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<pow(i,2) && count<heapItem.size(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << heapItem[count++]->b << "   ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    //make_heap, push_heap, pop_heap maintain min heap structure

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I think with the std heap operations, you would have to pop items off the heap until you find the one that you want to change, make the change, then push it and the other items back onto the heap.  Creating your own heap that keeps a reverse index shouldn't be that difficult though.

Comment: @VaughnCato thank you for the suggestion. The code above is simply a test code. It will be incorporated into a large code and Nx, Ny are on the order of 1000s. Popping back & finding seems much too costly. I have a feeling I should just write my own code for making and maintaining my heap.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a heap of A* pointers. You need the **index** of an A* obj in the heap in order to preserve heap structure after manipulating obj. There is no way to get it other than searching the entire heap. Here are some options:

1. Only manipulate the top of the heap, where it is obvious how to to get the index. This is how you're supposed to use non-intrusive heaps.
2. Implement your own intrusive heap where struct A has an index member. You need your own heap functions which update it.